# Vue.js - How to use an array in function for looping

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to use a JS array in Vue.js function for looping.

Tried code:

Vue:

```
computed: {
 bbb: function(){
  var vvv=this.Preused.length-this.quote.lines.length;
  let added_products=[];
  if(vvv > 0){
    for(var i = 0; i <= vvv-1; i++){
      newly_used.push({...this.Preused[this.manage.code.length+i]});
    }
  }
  return newly_used;
 }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div v-for="(cc,index) in bbb">
  <p v-text="cc[index].num"></p>
</div>
```

newly_used:

```
0:
  none: "calibry"
  des: "Silver"
  num: "numty"
```

By using the above code I am getting the following error;

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'num' of undefined"

How Can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cc.num` may work, cc is single item in bbb, and you shoule check if cc exist

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through `newly_used` properties which is returned from computed property so your v-for should be like :

```
<div v-for="(cc,index) in bbb" :key="index">
  <p v-text="cc.num"></p>
</div>
```

or

```
<div v-for="(cc,key,index) in bbb" :key="index">
  <p v-text="bbb[key].num"></p>
</div>
```